# I want to know which is the correct use of apostrophe s?

Tags: apostrophe

I want to know the correct use of apostrophe s?
Is the 's' used either in small or capital letter.
Which is right format either Ram's or Ram'S?
Please answer me soon.

Comment: *Ram's* is correct. Please visit http://www.ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where have you ever seen Ram'S?`Where have you ever seen Ram, for that matter?

Comment: Ram could also be a name or a nickname, apart from the animal, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Never a capitalized S after " **'** ".
But RAM is an acronym and the letters should be capitalized.

Write RAM's ; however it is unusual, please give a context.
"RAM's hindrance is that they are volatile" is correct.

For instance, you write "the RAM-capacity is", "the RAM has xyz Kb, or xy Gb", rather than "the RAM's capacity is", however formally correct.

Comment: Ram isn't necessarily an acronym. A ram is a male sheep.